# Nodejs Dotenv config variable is not working...Even Not any secrete key

Tags: node.js, server, environment-variables

Nodejs Dotenv config variable is not working...Even Not any secrete key is coming from process.env.variable.

See code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaDYA.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biDNc.png)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be, that port 5000 already is in use?
proccess.env is working on line 14 as it looks.

Insert a console.log(process.env) in line 13. I think it will work.

Comment: Got it.. it is semicolon I added in the .env file.. after removing semicolon it ok now. thanks